# partial postback creating mutliple instances of jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

after partial post back I am getting four instance of jquery plugin ,

I am not able to replicate it how its being done

```
<div class="ui-multiselect-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 427px;">

<div class="ui-multiselect-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 427px;">

<div class="ui-multiselect-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 427px;">

<div class="ui-multiselect-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 427px; top: 100px; left:
```

please help I am kind of stuck on this from 3 days

Comment: Can you post more code please or a link to a jsfiddle.com example?

Comment: actually its very lenght code, i am using multiselect jquery

Answer (score 0):

You could try Removing the Old one and Recreate new one. or Use an If condition to check existing of the block. If Null then create the block. This things happen in Asp.Net because of Page Refresh.. even in UpdatePanel